# How can I make my application launch at “Listen To” command in Siri?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, siri

How can I make my application launch at “Listen To ..” command in Siri ?

For example, applications like Spotify, Netflix, Discord or VLC launch when you say “Listen to ..” (Listen to Spotify, Listen to Netflix).

I tried to do that, but every time I say Listen to AppName, Siri gives me a response like : “I couldn’t find ’AppName’ in your music.” or “Sorry, I’m unable to do that."